# Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, kubernetes, mime-types

I deployed my angular application(Static webpage) on kubernetes and tried launching it from Google Chrome. I see app is loading, however there is nothing displayed on the browser. Upon checking on browser console , I could see this error

"Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."
for (main.js,poylfill.js,runtime.js) files . I research few forums and one possible rootcause could because of `type` attribute in `<script>` tag should be type=text/javascript instead of `type=module` in my index.html file that is produced under dist folder after executing ng build. I don't how to make that change as to these tags as generated during the build process, and my ng-build command is taken care by a docker command.

URL i'm trying to access will be something like : "http://xxxx:portnum/issuertcoetools

note: The host `xxxx:portnum` will be used by many other apps as well.

Are there any work-arounds or solutions to this issue?

index.html - produced after running ng-build in local, (which is the same i see in kubernetes POD too)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Data Generator</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}</style>
    <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Material Icons';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v128/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) format('woff2');}.material-icons{font-family:'Material Icons';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:24px;line-height:1;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:normal;direction:ltr;-webkit-font-feature-settings:'liga';-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}</style>
<style>.mat-typography{font:400 14px/20px Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;letter-spacing:normal}html,body{height:100%}body{margin:0;font-family:Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.9c0548760c8b22be.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.9c0548760c8b22be.css"></noscript></head>

<body class="mat-typography">
    <app-root></app-root>
 
<script src="runtime.397c3874548e84cd.js" type="module">
</script><script src="polyfills.2145acc81d0726ab.js" type="module">
</script><script src="main.a655dca28148b7e2.js" type="module"></script>

</body></html>
```

nginx.conf file

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

  location /issuertcoetools {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This error usually happens because you deployment was into a subfolder, so it seems like Angular is fetching you app directly from your base URL, so your html is found when you go to your `domain.com/mysubfolder/index.html`, but as the Angular fetches your resources from `domain.com/index.html` instead of domain.com/mysubfolder/index.html; I’m pretty sure this is the cause of your issue. You can resolve it building your app with:

```
ng build --prod --base-href mysubfolder
```

Comment: Late update, the solution given by you worked . However on the latest version of angular “—base-href” is deprecated. the given solution can only be implemented by declaring  APP_BASE_HREF value in NgModule section on app.module.ts file .. dtls here       https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

Answer (score 14):

Fixed the issue in my case by disabling the browser cache:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I was trying to add an Angular app in a subdirectory.

[@Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17894104/leo)'s
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72309023/15505755) is correct.
I made it manually by changing the base reference in `index.html`.

From `<base href="">` to `<base href="http://subdomain.domain.com/subdirectory/">` and it worked!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Website</title>
    <!-- <base href=""> -->
    <base href="http://subdomain.domain.com/subdirectory/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

<body>...</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it seems to work fine (no more problem when I copy/paste the url in the browser). This "trick" works in conjunction with url rewriting set either in the web.config file on IIS or in the .htaccess file on Apache. Url rewriting avoid to use hash symbol in url. Url rewriting avoid us to use the disgraceful hash symbol in url.

Comment: This worked for me! However, I have local, dev, and prod deployments so hard coding the entire URL wasn't an option for me. So, I just did: <base href="/en/" />

Answer (score 4):

Check `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` In the NGINX conf, that path may have an error, lean on the logs (nginx).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32426311)

Comment: This got it for me. Def check this out if you're using NGNIX from an angular app. Even if it "worked" previously

Comment: This is valid answer.

Comment: This was also my problem. This fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**

Go to *angular.json* and update the *outputPath* parameter to just *dist* instead of *dist/YourAppName*. Now you can use `ng build --configuration production` to build your app.

**Explanation:**

The problem is that when you run the command `ng build --configuration production` then the solution is outputted into dist/YourAppName and then paths get's broken because Angular think your app is in your root folder, but it is in root/YourAppName. Doing the above puts your app in root folder.

Comment: This one worked for me, changing output path to just "dist". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you can run    `ng build --base-href=/subdomain/`
or you can also add to angular.json

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "baseHref": "/subdomain/",
        ......
      } }
```

Answer (score 1):

We had few sites live ~1 month and one day we started facing `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"` problem. We did not change nginx config before this issue, but we thought that the problem was related to nginx.

Everything was ok with Nginx, the problem was with Cloudflare caching, so do the next:

- enable Development mode in Cloudflare (here we disable Cloudflare caching)
- open site (we should see our site without any problems)
- disable Development mode in Cloudflare (here we enable Cloudflare caching)

Answer (score 0):

when you host angular projects on virtual directory, you need to add:

```
 APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/YOUR VIRTUAL DIRECTORY NAME'
```

to "app.module.ts" in "NgModule" section. like this:

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/YOUR_VIRTUALDIRECTORY_NAME'}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

and rebuild your project.

don't forget to use:

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
```

*you can see about this, on https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF*

**and finally run:**

```
ng build --base-href  YOUR_VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY_NAME
```

have a good time!

Answer (score 0):

I commented out `<base href="/">` from `index.html` and my app displays on the server.

And I changed the `outputPath` in `angular.json` to not include the subdomain: `"outputPath": "dist",`.

I also changed the `public` setting in `firebase.json` to *include* the subdomain: `"public": "dist/en-US",`.

Why the different settings in `angular.json` and `firebase.json`? Before these changes, I had `angular.json` set to `"outputPath": "dist/language-two13",`. The result was that `ng build` transpiled my Angular project into `dist/language-two13/en-US`. By changing this setting I got rid of one subdomain.

In the browser neither subdomain appeared in the URL.

Where the `en-US` subdomain is coming from I have no idea. I'm using Transloco for i18n but searching through `transloco-root.module.ts` I see `en` and `es` as the languages of my project, not `en-US`. I searched my entire app and found only a few instances of `en-US`, only in code that corrects this to `en`, and never in settings that would affect the transpiler.

I tried switching the default language of Transloco from `en` to `es`. Nada cambios...no changes.

I tried commenting out Transloco in `app.module.ts` but Angular won't compile.

I tried moving my files from `dist/en-US/` to `dist`, removing the `en-US` folder, changing `firebase.json` to `"public": "dist",` and commenting `<base href="/">` back into `index.html`, and deploying to Firebase Hosting. This works fine.

In conclusion, `angular.json` is set to transpile without a subdomain, but the `en-US` subdomain is magically getting inserted, so I set `firebase.json` to correct for this weird behavior.

My hat is off to dev-ops professionals who deal with this stuff all day!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was actually my mistake. I looked for the file  `runtime.[random-numbers].js` which was highlighted in the error

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I could not find it. I realised I had not updated the list of files in FileZilla after I built my Angular app (the file names had changed since Angular randomises the file names)

I hope this saves someone some time :)

Answer (score 0):

If using AWS amplify make sure you add the extension to the rewrite list

</^[^.]+$|.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json|html|xlsx|mjs|webmanifest|properties)$)([^.]+$)/>

[image]