# I have two react applications under the same host from nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, gke-networking

I am having an ingress resource as below

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-staging
  namespace: staging
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-staging-production
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($request_uri ~* "^/\?.*") {
        add_header Content-Type text/javascript;
      }
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - afriven.com
    secretName: ingress-staging-secret
  rules:
    - host: app.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: afriven-frontend-service-staging
                port:
                  number: 80

          - path: /vendor/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: afriven-vendor-service-staging
                port:
                  number: 80

          - path: /backend/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: afriven-backend-service-staging
                port:
                  number: 5000
```

However only app.com and app.com/backend are working.

afriven-frontend-service-staging and afriven-vendor-service-staging server react build that from an nginx docker containers.

If I comment out

```
 - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: afriven-frontend-service-staging
                port:
                  number: 80
```

and change the path of this

```
- path: /vendor/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: afriven-vendor-service-staging
                port:
                  number: 80
```

to /?(.*) it works, other than that, i keep getting `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec`

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens because your deployment was into a subfolder, not directly on your base-URL.

To fix it

Build your angular app with

```
ng build --prod --base-href yoursubfolder
```

Or set the base path in your index.html

```
<head> 
    <base href="/yoursubfolder/"> 
</head>
```

Refer to this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72070748/failed-to-load-module-script-expected-a-javascript-module-script-but-the-server)  for more information.

Comment: OP was referring to React, not an Angular application.