# Problem in Routing that must fall back to index.html in Angular 15, ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, and hosted on IIS 10 in Azure

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, url-routing, asp.net-core-6.0

When I refresh a page like this (/category/details/1)

I got an error

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
> changed, or is temporarily unavailable

I solved the problem by using Hash Location

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

in providers in app.module but it made the routing link like this (#/category/details/1) and that is not accepted.

In .NET Core, I tried to implement this function in the program.cs

```
var app = builder.Build();

// fallback route to serve index.html for all deep links
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();

            // if no response was sent back by other middleware, and the request path 
            //doesn't start with "/api",serve the index.html file
 
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && 
               !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }
        });
```

And in Angular - I created a `web.config` file and placed it next to `index.html` file in the `(dist)` folder and implemented

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and added

```
// in the app.module
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
```

But I still got this error:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

This is the response header:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 4115
Content-Type: text/html
ETag: W/"0e9ce283e83d91:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: Same error you can use as reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/72309023/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72309023/13336642).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following code in your `Program.cs`

```cs
app.UseWhen(x => x.Request.Path.Value != null && !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), b =>
{
    b.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Request.Path = new PathString("/index.html");
        return next();
    }).UseStaticFiles();
});
```

Are you also using the code middleware below:

```cs
.
.
.
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

.
.
.
```

Comment: Same problem + the images from the server are not shown,

 **This is the error from the console**

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

Comment: So I think your problem might be that you have deployed your Web API/Angular app to IIS as a sub application under the main website? Could you try setting your baseHref in your angular.json file to match your application name/path. Also perhaps your answer may be here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72070748/failed-to-load-module-script-expected-a-javascript-module-script-but-the-server For example http://localhost/myApp you would set baseHref  as  "production": {
              "baseHref": "/myApp/",
              "budgets": [

Comment: this is my index.html
`  <base href="/"> ` and this is my link `http://localhost:4200`,
angula.json => "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "2mb"
               }
there is no  { "baseHref": "/myApp/", }