# Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". (Angular + Azure CDN)

Tags: angular, azure-storage, azure-cdn

I am using `angular` and Azure classic CDN to host the pages with custom domain configuration.

I am using `ng new angular-tour-of-heroes` from [Create a new workspace and an initial application](https://Create%20a%20new%20workspace%20and%20an%20initial%20application) to create a new angular project.

In this angular.json file, I have the default build configurations.

```
"outputPath": "dist/angular-tour-of-heroes",
"index": "src/index.html",
"main": "src/main.ts",
"polyfills": ["zone.js"]
```

The package.json file has the default.

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  }
```

Finally, I am using the following command to build my production.

```
ng build --configuration production
```

I am copying the whole content of the dist/angular-tour-of-heroes folder the $web folder in the Azure storage.

So the contents of the $web folder are

index.html
main.*.js
polyfills.*.js
runtime.*.js
styles.*.css
favicon.ico
3rdpartylicense.txt

and the **index.html** file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularTourOfHeroes</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.ef46db3751d8e999.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.6e50dac17b84e715.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.716cc9a230a87077.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.93983fc3aa1a4437.js" type="module"></script>

</body></html>
```

When moving the files to $web folder in the Azure storage, I get a white screen with the following errors in the console.

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but
> the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type
> checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

[image: Console screen shot]

On the other side, If I replace the index.html with a very basic HTML page and upload it to $web folder in the Azure storage. The site works as expected.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <bod>
    <h1>Something here</h1>
  </bod>
</html>
```

I have tried many links to find a solution, but yet to make any success.
[Failed to load module script](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/42548)
[Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72070748/failed-to-load-module-script-expected-a-javascript-module-script-but-the-server)

**CDN configuration**

```
Modify response header Overwrite X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Modify response header Overwrite  Content-Security-Policy default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self';
Modify response header Append Content-Security-Policy script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'
```

Is there any way to configure CDN to allow js files?

Additionally, If I use the direct link from the Azure storage->Static Website, the website is loading correctly. (e.g)
https://something.z13.web.core.windows.net/

Comment: The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77599375/azure-static-website-with-azure-cdn-shows-white-screen-only). An Azure CDN rule was causing the issue.