# Flutter - No default storage bucket could be found

Tags: angular, iis

I have an Angular 15 application that has been running for a while. Today after building it I started getting the following error messages.

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. runtime.b580d1d6b356fd8d.js:1

Refused to apply style from 'https://localhost/...../styles.e9eb357208e916ca.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. vendor.30212ef5671b2157.js:1
  
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. polyfills.3c7708ecd69acd93.js:1  

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. main.efed3a741000d359.js:1

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

`ts.config.json` has this: `"strictTemplates": false` setting in place.

I have reset my IIS multiple times, restarted the computer, nothing helped. Any idea where to look for the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72070748/failed-to-load-module-script-expected-a-javascript-module-script-but-the-server)